# check for string to be list of integers separated by + signs in python

Tags: python, bash

I want to check that myvar to be `one or more integers separated by + signs`. Should this `re.search()` be enough?

```
myvar = "1+2+3"
if (re.search(r"^[0-9]+(\+[0-9]+)*$", myvar)):
    print "myvar should be + separated integers (%s)" % myvar
     sys.exit(1)
```

Then I realised that this will still work for incorrect cases like:

```
myvar = "1+2+3-4"
```

Comment: `[^0-9+]` means 'at least one char that is neither a digit nor `+`'. That is not the same as '+ separated integers'.

Comment: Deleted my answer because I found that I cannot figure out what you're looking for. What is `myvar` and what do you expect that print statement to say?

Comment: @200508519211022689616937 The syntax and semantics of the expression are the same for `grep` and python `re` for your case, what you describe you want to get is something else. The problem does not lie with the transition, but with the expression. So it is kind of impossible to answer your question now.

Comment: @luk32 point taken, thanks very much. This is not my code, so I'll investigate where does this come from and what was the intended behaviour and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I checked the meaning of the original grep, and although it was probably wrong or incomplete, the intended behaviour was the one in `myvar should be a list of integers separated by + signs`

Comment: The regexp you copied from my answer does *not* match `1+2+3-4`. So what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex free alternative is to use split:

```
myvars = ["+1", "1++2", "1+5", "1+2+3"]
for myvar in myvars:
    nums = myvar.split('+')
    for num in nums:
        try: int(num)
        except: print "error", myvar
```

*Gives:*

```
error +1
error 1++2
```

Answer (score 2):

> myvar should be + separated integers

Take this input:

```
$ cat in.txt 
1+2+3+4
1+2
foo 1+2 bar
foo 1+2
1+2 bar
1
+
```

Four of these lines contain *only* '+ separated integers':

```
$ grep -E '^[0-9]+(\+[0-9]+)*$' < in.txt 
1+2+3+4
1+2
1
```

So you initial regexp does not what you want it to do.

You can use this regexp in Python, too.

**Edit**

```
import re

with open("in.txt") as i:
    for line in i:
        m = re.search(r"^[0-9]+(\+[0-9]+)*$", line.strip())
        if m:
            print(line.strip() + " matches")
```

Output:

```
$ python match.py                                                                 :(
1+2+3+4 matches
1+2 matches
1 matches
```

Comment: Depending on OP's comment the last `*` in your expression might need to be `+`. In my experience, most "common sense" cases of regexes don't plan to match the mathematically trivial case (1 is a "list of plus separated integers" of size one, containing no plus because there is no other integer to separate it from).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That is possible. Being a mathematican I tend to interpret things in a strict way :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I now checked what the exact behaviour was supposed to be, and edited the question. Apologies that this answer is not relevant to the edited question anymore...